# How to pass value from one jsp to another jsp at dynamic

Tags: mysql, jsp-tags

The first page contains a href id.

```
<td>
  <a href=<%= "\"Company_database.jsp?Id=" + rs.getInt(1) + "\"" %> >
    <%= rs.getInt(1) %>
  </a>
</td>
```

how to use this is id for the second page.My second page requires this id value to be passed in the sql query.
The second page code is

```
String QueryString1 = "Select * from attendance where id='"+id'";
```

Comment: You could also pass that variable as a parameter in the url or you can make use of sessions.

Comment: @RaymondNijland How do i use it??